# How to uninstall Conan completely

Tags: pip, conan

I use Windows 10. I have installed Conan using virtualenv and pip. Then I have uninstalled Conan: `pip uninstall conan`. The user directory (`C:/Users/user`) contains `.conan` directory. Should I remove it manually or pip has some option to remove directories created by a package ?

Comment: pip will not remove it for you because it's not prepared with a post uninstall instruction. You have to remove manually.

Comment: @uilianries How?

Comment: @71GA besides running pip command, you will need to delete the conan home folder, located (usually) at you home folder (Unix systems): `~/.conan`, ~/.conan_server` and  `~/.conan2` (last only for Conan 2.x). If running Windows, besides `%USERPROFILE%/.conan` you should have a folder at `C:/.conan` too, because of short folders feature. And that's it, it should be enough.

Comment: @uilianries Are there any leftovers at `/etc` or maybe `/usr/local`?

Comment: @71GA Conan does not use those directories, as they require extra permissions.